# Differential geometry, equation, exercise problem

Tags: geometry, differential

There is a problem in the text " O'neill- Elementary differential geometry 2ed. 
[image]

In my opinion, some expressions in (a) are not correct. 
What's the exact meaning of following statement? 
" the equations can be solved for $u$ and $v$, with $(u,v)$ in $D$.
Does this mean the existence of solution ?

Comment: The meaning of "the  equations can be solved for $u$ and $v$, with $(u,v)$ in $D$" is "there exists $(u,v) \in D$ such that $p_1 = x_1(u,v)$, $p_2 = x_2(u,v)$ and $p_3 = x_3(u,v)$".

Comment: @posilon/ Thank you so much.

Comment: You 're welcome. I'm posting my previous comment as an answer, so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> The equations $$p_1=x_1(u,v), \quad p_2=x_2(u,v), \quad p_3=x_3(u,v)$$ can be solved for $u$ and $v$, with $(u,v)$ in $D$.

is equivalent to

> There exists $(u,v) \in D$ such that $$p_1=x_1(u,v), \quad p_2=x_2(u,v), \quad p_3=x_3(u,v).$$